Flutter is stuck at "Waiting for VM Service port to be available..."
I wanted to add widgets to my app and therefore had to gradle sync, upgrade gradle plugin, upgrade sdk, update many things in different files in the android folder and I updated android studio and moved my android sdk folder.
Now because of all that everything is messed up and I can not even start the app. When I do "flutter run -v" I get this at the end:
Waiting for VM Service port to be available...
and then it just stays like that forever
The package names are correct, MainActivity.kt is fine, I tried reinstalling and restarting everything possible (except vsc), I have no idea what else could be missing
I even did what chatgpt told me and you know it is bad when not even chatgpt can help you lol
EDIT:
this is the last part of the "flutter run -v" output:
[   +3 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk...
[   +1 ms] executing: D:\Brockdish\Programming\SDKs\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install -t -r D:\Brockdish\Programming\Flutter
Projects\clothes_ethics_app\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk
[+7765 ms] Performing Streamed Install
                    Success
[   +2 ms] Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk... (completed in 7,8s)
[   +5 ms] executing: D:\Brockdish\Programming\SDKs\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell echo -n d613de727cfacda75e7bd4e15d3f720ebf3e7c66 >
/data/local/tmp/sky.dev.jusoft.clotho.sha1
[ +218 ms] executing: D:\Brockdish\Programming\SDKs\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[+1482 ms] --------- beginning of main
                    09-05 18:36:18.886 D/ControlsListingControllerImpl( 1065): ServiceConfig reloaded, count: 0
[ +162 ms] executing: D:\Brockdish\Programming\SDKs\Android\platform-tools\adb.exe -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -f
0x20000000 --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true dev.jusoft.clotho/dev.jusoft.clotho.MainActivity
[+4143 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x20000000 cmp=dev.jusoft.clotho/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[   +2 ms] Waiting for VM Service port to be available...

